# How to fix if statement with two conditions in R (it stops after length 8)

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am adding a column to my data frame and with that column I am trying to group my data based on two conditions (difference in time and amount of distance). My code is composed of an ifelse statement for 50K observations, and it does just fine looping from row 1 to 7, but it refuses to loop past length 8. It didn't show me an error so I'm wondering, am I missing something in my code? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
df
j <- 1
df$GroupID <- NA
df$GroupID[1] <- 1
for (i in 2:length(df)) {
  flashes <- df[which(df$GroupID==j)]
  h <- cbind(flashes$Long,flashes$Lat)
  point <- cbind(df$Long[i],df$Lat[i])
  lastrow <- tail(flashes, n = 1)
  moment <- lastrow$DateTime
  
  ifelse (min(spDistsN1(h,point,longlat = TRUE))<16 & 
          difftime(df$DateTime[i],moment)<minutes(15),
          df$GroupID[i] <-j,df$GroupID[i] <-NA)

  #arrange(df[, "GroupID"])
}

j=j+1
```

The first rows of my data looks like this:

DateTime             Lat    Long    GroupID
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.478  81.066   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.479  81.068   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.482  81.066   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.475  81.085   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.484  81.084   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.492  81.080   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.080   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.081   1
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.494  81.078   NA
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.495  81.075   NA
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.497  81.075   NA
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.507  81.074   NA

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show expected output for the data shared?

Comment: I appreciate the assist, but someone was able to find the issue. It turns out i used length (counts the columns) instead of nrow (counts the rows). That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length()` of a data.frame is the number of columns it has, so simply use `nrow()` instead

```
df
j <- 1
df$GroupID <- NA
df$GroupID[1] <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  flashes <- df[which(df$GroupID==j)]
  h <- cbind(flashes$Long,flashes$Lat)
  point <- cbind(df$Long[i],df$Lat[i])
  lastrow <- tail(flashes, n = 1)
  moment <- lastrow$DateTime
  
  ifelse (min(spDistsN1(h,point,longlat = TRUE))<16 & 
          difftime(df$DateTime[i],moment)<minutes(15),
          df$GroupID[i] <-j,df$GroupID[i] <-NA)

  #arrange(df[, "GroupID"])
}

j=j+1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. It looks like it's going past 8 now. Now, that it is going, it looks like it is taking a minute. Any advice on how to speed up my code?

Comment: @Kate there are a few tricks, you could try on a small subset of the data (e.g. `df[1:300, ]` for the first 300 rows), and time it. Then try refactoring your code inside the loop to make it more efficient. Currently it has 5 assignments inside the loop, if you can somehow reduce that, it could improve performance. Sometimes it's necessary to let it run overnight (or longer) but I would always estimate how long it should take first, as well as check results on a smaller data frame to make sure the results are what you expected